# Why do Twitter Bootstrap tables always have 100% width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Suppose this markup:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" align="center">
```

No mather how many cells I have, the table is always 100% width. Why's that?

Comment: because it efficiently uses its parents width; that is how grid system should work!

Comment: What width do you want your table to be?

Comment: I would like it to be depent on number of cells, just like ordinary table

Comment: For those who searching how to set cell width like div width via span check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18498071/1339254)

Answer (score 244, accepted):

All tables within the bootstrap stretch according to their container, which you can easily do by placing your table inside a `.span*` grid element of your choice. If you wish to remove this property you can create your own table class and simply add it to the table you want to expand with the content within:

```
.table-nonfluid {
   width: auto !important;
}
```

You can add this class inside your own stylesheet and simply add it to the container of your table like so:

```
<table class="table table-nonfluid"> ... </table>
```

This way your change won't affect the bootstrap stylesheet itself (you might want to have a fluid table somewhere else in your document).

Comment: If you place the table inside a span* tag, in order to center the table, would you just include an offset*, too?

Comment: @dlackey Yes, you can offset the table with a class in order to center, you can even add a `.span*` class to your table to give it some width.

Comment: At least with bootstrap 3 it only worked for me after adding `!important` to the `width: auto`

Comment: we have to use bootstarp's span class for a table , or we have to manually give a style for .span class,

Comment: Warning. Be careful if used in combination with .table-responsive and .table-bordered. The border is applied to the .table-responsive container when below screen width 767px. (bootstrap 3.x)

Answer (score 36):

If you're using Bootstrap 4, use `.w-auto`.

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/sizing/

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want to keep it to bootstrap and make the table auto-size but not use the column size class within a row.

Answer (score 33):

`<table style="width: auto;" ...` works fine. Tested in Chrome 38 , IE 11 and Firefox 34.

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rpaul/taqodr8o/

Answer (score 17):

### Bootstrap 3:

Why fight it?  Why not simply control your table width using the bootstrap grid?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <table></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will create a table that is half (6 out of 12) of the width of the containing element.

I sometimes use inline styles as per the other answers, but it is discouraged.

### Bootstrap 4 and 5:

Bootstrap 4 has some nice helper classes for width like `w-25`, `w-50`, `w-75`, `w-100`, and `w-auto`.  This will make the table 50% width:

```
<table class="w-50"></table>
```

Here's the doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/

Comment: this is by far the simplest solution and should be the accepted answer

Comment: Personally I think the one above it is just as good but you're right, you can't go wrong with this one either way. Still works in BS5.

Answer (score 12):

I was having the same issue, I made the table fixed and then specified my td width. If you have th you can do those as well.

```
<style>
table {
table-layout: fixed;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>

<td width="10%" /td>
```

I didn't have any luck with .table-nonfluid.

Comment: Try `width: auto !important;`

Comment: You can avoid `!important` (it's a [bad practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception)). See comment on [an answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24245745/1323144).

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to add `style="width: auto !important"` and works great for me!

Comment: If you ensure that your custom CSS appears after the Bootstrap CSS (e.g. your custom styles `<link>` tag appears _below_ the Bootstrap `<link>` tag), then the rules will *cascade* as designed, and you shouldn't need to use your `!important` exception at all. This is true because `width: 100%;` is defined for `table` in the [Bootstrap CSS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/tables.less) and so is superseding your `width: auto;` rule.

Comment: Not really an answer, better to edit the current accepted answer which most of the people read _(I edited it now)_.