# How to set up fixed width for <td>?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width, html-table

Simple scheme:

```
  <tr class="something">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
```

I need to set up a fixed width for `<td>`. I've tried:

```
tr.something {
  td {
    width: 90px;
  }
}
```

Also

```
td.something {
  width: 90px;
}
```

for

```
<td class="something">B</td>
```

And even

```
<td style="width: 90px;">B</td>
```

But the width of `<td>` is still the same.

Comment: I just tried and it works - maybe the problem is somewhere different. What does Firebug tell you about the element?

Comment: [In this site](http://ericsaupe.com/custom-column-widths-in-bootstrap-tables/), man is telling about this topic with video. It is so clear.

Comment: use `style="width: 1% !important;"` to make the width as tight as the longest word in the column, it's useful for the first ID/# column. Tested in chrome(desktop&mobile), opera (desktop), IE(desktop), edge(desktop), firefox(desktop)

Answer (score 1296, accepted):

### For Bootstrap 4.0:

In Bootstrap 4.0.0 you cannot use the `col-*` classes reliably (works in Firefox, but not in Chrome).
You need to use [OhadR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34987484/2256700):

```
<tr>
  <th style="width: 16.66%">Col 1</th>
  <th style="width: 25%">Col 2</th>
  <th style="width: 50%">Col 4</th>
  <th style="width:  8.33%">Col 5</th>
</tr>
```

### For Bootstrap 3.0:

With twitter bootstrap 3 use: `class="col-md-*"` where * is a number of columns of width.

```
<tr class="something">
    <td class="col-md-2">A</td>
    <td class="col-md-3">B</td>
    <td class="col-md-6">C</td>
    <td class="col-md-1">D</td>
</tr>
```

### For Bootstrap 2.0:

With twitter bootstrap 2 use: `class="span*"` where * is a number of columns of width.

```
<tr class="something">
    <td class="span2">A</td>
    <td class="span3">B</td>
    <td class="span6">C</td>
    <td class="span1">D</td>
</tr>
```

** If you have `<th>` elements set the width there and not on the `<td>` elements.

Comment: What happens if you have more than 12 columns?

Comment: you can apply this only in the <head> in each <th> tag and all rows will match

Comment: Is there documentation about this on the Bootstrap website?

Comment: This works, but it's not on the bootstrap site because those col-* classes aren't meant to be used this way. They are meant to be used in the responsive bootstrap grids. If you like what these do, consider looking at the CSS for them and copy it to make your own CSS.

Comment: Also, instead of setting the class for reach row, we can simply set it once for the header <th> and the rest is taken care of automatically!

Comment: This is impractical. I have tried this and it not the best was given a certain number of columns needed. As you mentioned "fixed with", using col-sm-3, for example, if not fixed but responsive. I suggest using a fixed width table layout and applying px width like style="width: 120px". It works for me the way i want to. When the browser is resized, the table stays the same and I can scroll through the rest of it. Also, I have tried using various column sizes at mobile and desktop, it is still impractical for a table design and they still behaved in a responsive way.

Comment: Use col-xs-* if you want this to apply to all screen sizes.

Comment: Bootstrap 3 doesn't have `col-` classes for table cells.

Comment: In Bootstrap 4 you can also use classes to help with width: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-parent . E.g.: w-75 for 75% width.

Comment: First one works for Bootstrap 5 too!

Answer (score 173):

I was having the same issue, I made the table fixed and then specified my td width. If you have th you can do those as well.

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Template:

```
<td style="width:10%">content</td>
```

Please use CSS for structuring any layouts.

Comment: Sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881067/html-td-width-and-height, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement

Comment: This is great, but as an addition use a `class` in the `td` tag instead of applying the style directly

Comment: This works thanks  **better** just enough to increase the width of `th` like : `<th style="width: 25%;"></th>` this will effect other columns width

Comment: Thank you! I've set col-md-x class for Bootstrap 3 but it didn't work. Setting the table layout to "fixed" resolves my issue.

Comment: This works. The key is the `table-layout: fixed`. That's required because many templates built with BS4 apply flex to everything, including tables.

Answer (score 80):

Instead of applying the `col-md-*` classes to each `td` in the row you can create a `colgroup` and apply the classes to the `col` tag.

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <colgroup>
            <col class="col-md-4">
            <col class="col-md-7">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Long Value</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Demo [here](http://www.bootply.com/rNvsMxe7d8)

Comment: I prefer this but it seems not affect to my case, the column width not extend by col-md-*

Comment: I like this solution, by the way, why one is forced to use col-md-* classes and not col-lg-* ,col-sm-* or col-xs-*?

Comment: @LucioB you can use whichever you want and even use several of them by column (example `<col class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">` will have a width of 33% in medium screen size and 50% in small screen size)

Comment: Colgroup is not working in Chrome. (Bootstrap v4.1). For uniformity across browsers, use % width for <td> elements.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Exactly what I needed. Also Very flexible to use with different variations.

Answer (score 78):

Still works with Bootstrap 5.3.3:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 30%">Col 1</th>
      <th style="width: 20%">Col 2</th>
      <th style="width: 10%">Col 3</th>
      <th style="width: 30%">Col 4</th>
      <th style="width: 10%">Col 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 1</td>
      <td>Val 2</td>
      <td>Val 3</td>
      <td>Val 4</td>
      <td>Val 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Via [this 2011 issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/863). There might have been newer recommendations since then.

Answer (score 68):

If you're using `<table class="table">` on your table, Bootstrap's table class adds a width of 100% to the table. You need to change the width to auto.

Also, if the first row of your table is a header row, you might need to add the width to th rather than td.

Comment: As an addition on Bootstrap 3 you will also need to set the white-space property of the `th` to normal since it is nowrap currently as such headers won't break.

Answer (score 63):

In my case I was able to fix that issue by using `min-width: 100px` instead of `width: 100px` for the cells `th` or `td`.

```
.table td, .table th {
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This may have preserved what's left of my sanity.

Comment: Yes! this sets, well, the min-width for a column in a responsive table. Thanks.

Comment: this worked better than the answered question, thanks!

Comment: min-width worked for me where width did not, I'm guessing it's because I didn't make the table "fixed width" as I still wanted the rest of the columns to resize automatically.

Comment: This works for me too!

Answer (score 53):

For Bootstrap 4, you can use the width class helper:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="w-10">Col 1</td>
      <td class="w-40">Col 2</td>
      <td class="w-15">Col 3</td>
      <td class="w-35">Col 4</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background: yellow">Val 1</td>
      <td style="background: orange">Val 2</td>
      <td style="background: yellow">Val 3</td>
      <td style="background: orange">Val 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This fit for my use case. Thanks!

Comment: Important to note that the only w-* options are: `.w-25, .w-50, .w-75, .w-100, .w-auto` so if you want something else, say, `w-10` you will need to add `.w-10 { width: 10% !important; }` to your localized css file.

Comment: I've edited the code into an embeddable snippet, which showed it didn't work.

Answer (score 50):

## Bootstrap 4.0

On Bootstrap 4.0, we have to declare the table rows as flex-boxes by adding class d-flex, and also drop xs, md, suffixes to allow Bootstrap to automatically derive it from the viewport.

So it will look following:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="d-flex">
            <th class="col-2"> Student No. </th>
            <th class="col-7"> Description </th>
            <th class="col-3"> Amount </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="d-flex">
            <td class="col-2">test</td>
            <td class="col-7">Name here</td>
            <td class="col-3">Amount Here </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this will be helpful to someone else out there!

Cheers!

Comment: Note limitation on this: seems as though if you use d-flex you lose the ability to use the align-* helper functions for the fields. it no longer has an effect.

Comment: This do the trick, very helpful

Answer (score 16):

Bootstrap 4 and 5 have a width utility for resizing html element width
Example:

```
<tr class="w-50">
    <td class="w-25">A</td>
    ...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this -

```
<style>
 table { table-layout: fixed; }
 table th, table td { overflow: hidden; }
</style>
```

Comment: This is the only one that works out of all the other answers.

Comment: I also added `text-overflow: ellipsis` to make sure the cut-off text is apparent

Comment: @Observer07 Indeed

Answer (score 8):

This combined solution worked for me, I wanted equal width columns

```
<style type="text/css">

    table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

        table th, table td {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

</style>
```

Result :-

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Use d-flex instead of row for "tr" in Bootstrap 4**

The thing is that "row" class takes more width then the parent container, which introduces issues.

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-sm-8">Hello</td>
      <td class="col-sm-4">World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-sm-8">8 columns</td>
      <td class="col-sm-4">4 columns</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I meant "row" instead of "tr". As the row class comes with gutters on both ends. Or if you wan't to use the "row" class just add "no-gutters" class.

Comment: Note limitation on this: seems as though if you use d-flex or row classes you lose the ability to use the align-* helper functions for the fields. it no longer has an effect.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to judge without the context of the page html or the rest of your CSS. There might be a zillion reasons why your CSS rule is not affecting the td element.

Have you tried more specific CSS selectors such as

```
tr.somethingontrlevel td.something {
  width: 90px;
}
```

This to avoid your CSS being overridden by a more specific rule from the bootstrap css.

(by the way, in your inline css sample with the style attribute, you misspelled width - that could explain why that try failed!)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I just figured out where was the problem - in Bootstrap is set up as a default value `width` for `select` element, thus, the solution is:

```
tr. something {
  td {
    select {
      width: 90px;
    }
  }
}
```

Anything else doesn't work me.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I often do when I don't have to deal with IE

```
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="width: calc(1 * 100% / 12)">#</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: calc(4 * 100% / 12)">Website</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: calc(3 * 100% / 12)">Username</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: calc(3 * 100% / 12)">Password</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: calc(1 * 100% / 12)">Action</th>
    </tr>
```

That way you can have a familiar 12-col grid.

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with the issue for a while, so just in case when someone makes the same stupid mistake as me...
Inside the `<td>` I had the element with `white-space:pre` style applied. That made all my table/tr/td tricks discarded. When I removed that style, suddenly all my text was nicely formatted inside the `td`.

So, always check the main container (like `table` or `td`) but also, always check if you don't cancel your beautifull code somewhere deeper :)

Answer (score 2):

In bootstarp 4 you can use `row` and `col-*` in table, I use it as below

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="row">
            <th class="col-sm-3">3 row</th>
            <th class="col-sm-4">4 row</th>
            <th class="col-sm-5">5 row</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="col-sm-3">some text</td>
            <td class="col-sm-4">some text</td>
            <td class="col-sm-5">some text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Note limitation on this: seems as though if you use d-flex or row you lose the ability to use the align-* helper functions for the fields. it no longer has an effect.

Answer (score 2):

use fixed table layout css in table, and set a percent of the td.

Answer (score 1):

**I also faced this problem and I follow this approach to overcome...So you can try**

`<td style="min-width:120px;">B</td>`

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code - it is very hard to understand something when it isn't explained. Please also provide the full code.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i solved it this way

```
<style>
td {
    min-width: 175px;
}
</style>
```

So every table cell gets a mininum width of 175px. You may change the value to fit it to your purposes.

You can find more about min-width here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width?retiredLocale=de

Answer (score 0):

None of this work for me, and have many cols on datatable to make % or sm class equals to 12 elements layout on bootstrap.

I was working with datatables Angular 5 and Bootstrap 4, and have many cols in table. The solution for me was in the `TH` to add a `DIV` element with a specific width. For example for the cols "Person Name" and "Event date" I need a specific width, then  put a `div` in the col header, the entire col width then resizes to the width specified from the div on the `TH`:

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" *ngIf="listData" class="table table-hover table-sm table-bordered text-center display" width="100%">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID </th>
            <th scope="col">Value</th>
            <th scope="col"><div style="width: 600px;">Person Name</div></th>
            <th scope="col"><div style="width: 800px;">Event date</div></th> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, setting the table's layout to auto and targeting the specific columns' `<th>` did the trick. I found that targeting `<td>` in any of the rows works as well. Feel free to throw in `!important` if you need to.

```
.table {
  table-layout: auto;
}

th {
 width: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use **.something** without **td** or **th**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
  <style>
    .something {
      width: 90px;
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Fixed width column</h2>            
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="something">Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

in Bootstrap Table 4.x

If you are creating the table in the init parameters instead of using HTML.

You can specify the width parameters in the columns attribute:

```
$("table").bootstrapTable({
    columns: [
        { field: "title", title: "title", width: "100px" }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score -5):

```html
<div class="row" id="divcashgap" style="display:none">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-default" id="gvcashgapp">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="1">BranchCode</th>
                                    <th class="2"><a>TC</a></th>
                                    <th class="3">VourNo</th>
                                    <th class="4"  style="min-width:120px;">VourDate</th>
                                    <th class="5" style="min-width:120px;">RCPT Date</th>
                                    <th class="6">RCPT No</th>
                                    <th class="7"><a>PIS No</a></th>
                                    <th class="8" style="min-width:160px;">RCPT Ammount</th>
                                    <th class="9">Agging</th>
                                    <th class="10" style="min-width:160px;">DesPosition Days</th>
                                    <th class="11" style="min-width:150px;">Bank Credit Date</th>
                                    <th class="12">Comments</th>
                                    <th class="13" style="min-width:150px;">BAC Comment</th>
                                    <th class="14">BAC Ramark</th>
                                    <th class="15" style="min-width:150px;">RAC Comment</th>
                                    <th class="16">RAC Ramark</th>
                                    <th class="17" style="min-width:120px;">Update Status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tbdCashGapp"></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Add some explanation too.

Comment: This answer is confusing at best. Classes are weird, non-essential ids, no explanation.

Comment: Using CSS in this manner is quite irresponsible. If you have unique identifiers, you should be using ID, first off. Secondly, using pixels is miserable when it comes to responsiveness. Thirdly, you should never define css in this manner anyway, you will never be able to maintain this in the future. And finally, as stated above, you need to explain your reasoning.