# CSS - create table with fixed size and custom column sizes

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created these CSS classes:

```
        .table-c {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width:100%;
            height: 30px;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
        .table-c td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

And this table:

```
                   <table class="table-c">
                        <tr>
                            <td>REFERENCE NO.</td>
                            <td>DESCRIPTION</td>
                            <td>Invoice DATE</td>
                            <td>INVOICE AMOUNT</td>
                            <td>DISCOUNT TAKEN</td>
                            <td>AMOUNT PAID</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CHECK DATA</td>
                            <td>CHECK NO.</td>
                            <td>PAYEE</td>
                            <td>DISCOUNT TAKEN</td>
                            <td>CHECK AMOUNT</td>                                
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>                           
                    </table>
```

Table is fixed size as I wanted, but I also need to have different columns have different width. Those columns should not change with and always have it fixed. And also rows height should be fixed.

As in this example:

[image]

Here is my try:
http://jsfiddle.net/cbafseq6/

As you can see all columns have same width and all rows same height. If I would try for example set height on specific `tr` element (like `style="height: 20px"`) all rows would still have same height.

Comment: Andrius can you not use Bootstrap? Possible help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text-in-its-cell and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115052/bootstrap-how-to-set-up-fixed-width-for-td

Comment: The "problems" you have are caused by *how tables are meant to work*. For different column widths, you will need separate tables. All cells in one row will always automatically have the same height as the one with the highest content. Also, you *cannot control or limit* the height of a table-cell - it is always defined by its content (at least the min-height). Also, you cannot control `overflow` on table-cells, neither x nor y.

Comment: @connexo, if you want to control overflow, you can. Anyway, you can change `display` property to any nontable value and use table as it was not a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want every row to have specific height and every column to have specific width, you can do something like the code below. I used your own code. You can tell me if that helps.

```css
.table-c {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width:100%;
            height: 30px;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
        .table-c td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<table class="table-c">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 10%">REFERENCE NO.</td>
    <td style="width: 30%">DESCRIPTION</td>
    <td style="width: 10%">Invoice DATE</td>
    <td style="width: 10%">INVOICE AMOUNT</td>
    <td style="width: 20%">DISCOUNT TAKEN</td>
    <td style="width: 20%">AMOUNT PAID</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 200px">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table-c">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20%">CHECK DATA</td>
    <td style="width: 10%">CHECK NO.</td>
    <td style="width: 40%">PAYEE</td>
    <td style="width: 10%">DISCOUNT TAKEN</td>
    <td style="width: 20%">CHECK AMOUNT</td>                                
  </tr> 
  <tr style="height: 200px">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>                           
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, while saving I lost some code :P I updated my answer!

Comment: Same as mine, but with extra separation line between tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the `table` element is what you want to go with.

Custom width of cells within columns would be available by using multiple tables (one for each row), perhaps, but a single table cannot have columns change width every row.

Maybe try a `div` layout.

Regarding the height set on `tr` - you chose a height too small, so there is no effect, a larger value would make the row larger. Again, because of `table` display settings this works differently and you should probably look for a different layout option.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 2 tables:

```css
table {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  margin-top: -2px; /* same value as border-spacing */
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
} 

table:first-child {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

table:last-child {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>REFERENCE NO.</td>
      <td>DESCRIPTION</td>
      <td>Invoice DATE</td>
      <td>INVOICE AMOUNT</td>
      <td>DISCOUNT TAKEN</td>
      <td>AMOUNT PAID</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>CHECK DATA</td>
      <td>CHECK NO.</td>
      <td>PAYEE</td>
      <td>DISCOUNT TAKEN</td>
      <td>CHECK AMOUNT</td>                                
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>                           
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `border-collapse: collapse;` that to make it more akin to his original example.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I would need 4 tables? Because I need custom height for every row.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon, I expected that he wants spacing. Yes, it's possible to add `border-collapse: collapse;` and remove `border-spacing: 2px; margin-top: -2px;`.

Comment: @Andrius, how does the height depends on number of tables?

Comment: Well setting `tr` to specific height does not work. So I wonder how can I specify different height for different row?

Comment: @Andrius, why? Anyway, you can set the minimal height to any cell in the row.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, even though tables are meant to display tabular data, I would go with a div layout here.

You can easily do this with a wrapper and some floated div and then you can do any and all customization you like to any of the "cells". Just my .02