# Text shifting elements bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following table using bootstrap when there is too much text:

[image]

It pushes the column down and doesn't even come close to filling the whole area before pushing the size of the row... Plus the text isn't aligned with itself. I tried text-align in css to fix this but found no answers there.

Here is the **code** for the mess with no additions just generic:

```
   <div class="container">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Event</th>
                        <th>Last Ran</th>
                        <th>Next Run</th>
                        <th>Options</th>
                        <th>Details</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (PIM5.Web.Models.Event evt in Model.Events)
                    {
                        <tr class=@evt.status>
                            <td><b>@evt.name</b></td>
                            <td>@evt.lastRan</td>
                            <td>@evt.nextRun</td>
                            <td style="max-width: 150px">
                                @if (evt.options > 0)
                                {
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  onclick="doProcessStart('@evt.name')">Start</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"  onclick="doProcessStop('@evt.name')">Stop</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="doProcessEdit('@evt.name')">Edit</button>
                                }

                                @if (evt.options > 1)
                                {
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Force</button>
                                }
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="doProcessRemove('@evt.name')">Remove</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>@evt.description</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="doAddEvent()">New Event</button>
        </div>
```

This is what I would like it to do:
[image]

**Fill the black box area first before pushing row down** and **never increase the row width and go off screen**

Willing to use javascript or anything that will fix this problem.

Comment: give fixed width to each column

Comment: fixed width is no good for mobile devices - use % widths - in this case though use bootstrap columns as already using bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the built in bootstrap styles col-md-*. This was answered in this question: [Bootstrap - how to set up fixed width for <td>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115052/bootstrap-how-to-set-up-fixed-width-for-td)

> For Bootstrap 3.0:
>
> With twitter bootstrap 3 use: class="col-md-*" where * is a number of
>   columns of width.
>
> ```
> <tr class="something">  
>     <td class="col-md-2">A</td>  
>     <td class="col-md-3">B</td>  
>     <td class="col-md-6">C</td>  
>     <td class="col-md-1">D</td> </tr>
> ```
>
> For Bootstrap 2.0:
>
> With twitter bootstrap 2 use: class="span*" where * is a number of
>   columns of width.
>
> ```
> <tr class="something">  
>     <td class="span2">A</td>  
>     <td class="span3">B</td>  
>     <td class="span6">C</td>  
>     <td class="span1">D</td> </tr>
> ```
>
> ** If you have <th> elements set the width there and not on the <td> elements.

Comment: The table still expands to cause overflow-x

Comment: Adding `word-wrap: break-word;` to the style of the td should fix it

Answer (score 1):

Here is the css you could use - similar idea unpollo had:

```
.evtstatus td:last-child {
    max-width: 200px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

For it to work you need to apply the class "eventstatus" to the tr.
I also use max-width in case there is less text.

Answer (score 0):

Give your THs widths, that will limit the width of the corresponding TDs. You can also play with word-break to make sure long words wrap properly (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/)