# Bootstrap alignment issue with table-responsive

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a calendar in ASP.NET MVC that dynamically adds anchor links to each day based on whats stored in  a SQL database for that specific day. I'm using a html tables with the `table-responsive` class to format the widths and such.

Basically, I would like all the columns be responsive in the table, but somewhat fixed.  Depending on the number of anchors added to the col-xs-12, it can look right (Day 5 & 6 in picture below) or add spacing to the right.  The spacing to the right with multiple anchor elements or, events, is my problem.  How do i go about fixing this?  Should I add another row for 2 or more buttons?  I'm not sure how to approach this problem, I'm not an expert ui person.  Any help would be appreciated.  I can provide any other files needed.

[image]

html:

```
<div id="calendarContainer">
    <div class="panel panel-default container-fluid mt25">
        <div class="panel-heading row">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <h2><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> January 2017</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" onclick="getAdjacentMonth('12/6/2016 12:00:00 AM')"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-4x pull-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <div>
                        <div id="clock" class="">7:44:45 pm</div>
                        <div>Monday, January 16, 2017</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" onclick="getAdjacentMonth('2/6/2017 12:00:00 AM')">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-4x pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="calendarBody">
        <table id="calendarData" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr id="headerRow" class="text-center">
                    <td class="headerDay text-nowrap">
                        <span>Sunday</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="headerDay text-nowrap">
                        <span>Monday</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="headerDay text-nowrap">
                        <span>Tuesday</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="headerDay text-nowrap">
                        <span>Wednesday</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="headerDay text-nowrap">
                        <span>Thursday</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="headerDay text-nowrap">
                        <span>Friday</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="headerDay text-nowrap">
                        <span>Saturday</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="currentMonthBackground">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-xs-1">
                                <div class="currentMonthDay">2</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-1 mml5">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus" title="Toggle dropdown menu"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a onclick="addReminder('1/2/2017 12:00:00 AM')"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> Reminder</a></li>
                                    <li><a onclick="addComment('1/2/2017 12:00:00 AM')"><i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o fa-fw"></i> Note</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs inline mobileReminder " onclick="displayNote('1/2/2017 12:00:00 AM')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o fa-fw"></i><span class="eventSizeSmall">1</span>
                                </a>

                                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs inline mobileReminder " onclick="displayReminder('1/2/2017 12:00:00 AM')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> <span class="eventSizeSmall">1</span>
                                </a>

                                <a class="btn btn-birthday btn-xs inline mobileReminder " onclick="displayBirthday('1/2/2017 12:00:00 AM')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-birthday-cake fa-fw"></i><span class="eventSizeSmall">1</span>
                                </a>

                                <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs mobileReminder" onclick="displayHoliday('1/2/2017 12:00:00 AM')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-bullhorn fa-fw"></i><span class="eventSizeSmall">1</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                    <td class="currentMonthBackground">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-xs-1">
                                <div class="currentMonthDay">3</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-1 mml5">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus" title="Toggle dropdown menu"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a onclick="addReminder('1/3/2017 12:00:00 AM')"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> Reminder</a></li>
                                    <li><a onclick="addComment('1/3/2017 12:00:00 AM')"><i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o fa-fw"></i> Note</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs inline mobileReminder " onclick="displayNote('1/3/2017 12:00:00 AM')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o fa-fw"></i><span class="eventSizeSmall">1</span>
                                </a>

                                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs inline mobileReminder " onclick="displayReminder('1/3/2017 12:00:00 AM')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> <span class="eventSizeSmall">1</span>
                                </a>

                                <a class="btn btn-birthday btn-xs inline mobileReminder " onclick="displayBirthday('1/3/2017 12:00:00 AM')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-birthday-cake fa-fw"></i><span class="eventSizeSmall">1</span>
                                </a>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                    <td class="currentMonthBackground">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-xs-1">
                                <div class="currentMonthDay">4</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-1 mml5">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus" title="Toggle dropdown menu"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a onclick="addReminder('1/4/2017 12:00:00 AM')"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> Reminder</a></li>
                                    <li><a onclick="addComment('1/4/2017 12:00:00 AM')"><i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o fa-fw"></i> Note</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </td>
                    <td class="currentMonthBackground">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-xs-1">
                                <div class="currentMonthDay">5</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-1 mml5">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus" title="Toggle dropdown menu"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a onclick="addReminder('1/5/2017 12:00:00 AM')"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> Reminder</a></li>
                                    <li><a onclick="addComment('1/5/2017 12:00:00 AM')"><i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o fa-fw"></i> Note</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs inline mobileReminder " onclick="displayNote('1/5/2017 12:00:00 AM')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o fa-fw"></i><span class="eventSizeSmall">1</span>
                                </a>



                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                    <td class="currentMonthBackground">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-xs-1">
                                <div class="currentMonthDay">6</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-1 mml5">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus" title="Toggle dropdown menu"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a onclick="addReminder('1/6/2017 12:00:00 AM')"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> Reminder</a></li>
                                    <li><a onclick="addComment('1/6/2017 12:00:00 AM')"><i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o fa-fw"></i> Note</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs inline mobileReminder " onclick="displayNote('1/6/2017 12:00:00 AM')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o fa-fw"></i><span class="eventSizeSmall">1</span>
                                </a>

                                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs inline mobileReminder " onclick="displayReminder('1/6/2017 12:00:00 AM')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> <span class="eventSizeSmall">1</span>
                                </a>


                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                    <td class="currentMonthBackground">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-xs-1">
                                <div class="currentMonthDay">7</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-1 mml5">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus" title="Toggle dropdown menu"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a onclick="addReminder('1/7/2017 12:00:00 AM')"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> Reminder</a></li>
                                    <li><a onclick="addComment('1/7/2017 12:00:00 AM')"><i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o fa-fw"></i> Note</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="modalBodyContainer"></div>
</div>
```

mvc calendar.cshtml:

```
<div id="calendarContainer">
    <div class="panel panel-default container-fluid mt25">
        <div class="panel-heading row">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <h2><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> @Model.MonthData.Name @Model.MonthData.Year</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" onclick="getAdjacentMonth('@Model.CurrentCalendarDate.AddMonths(-1)')"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-4x pull-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <div>
                        <div id="clock" class="">loading...</div>
                        <div>@DateTime.Now.ToString("D", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" onclick="getAdjacentMonth('@Model.CurrentCalendarDate.AddMonths(+1)')">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-4x pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="calendarBody">
        <table id="calendarData" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr id="headerRow" class="text-center">
                    @foreach (var day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).OfType<DayOfWeek>().ToList())
                    {
                        <td class="headerDay text-nowrap">
                            <span>@day.ToString()</span>
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var week in Model.MonthData.WeeksInMonth)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @if (Model.PrefixDays.Any() && week.WeekNumber == Model.MonthData.NumberOfWeeks.First())
                        {
                            foreach (var prefixDay in Model.PrefixDays)
                            {
                                <td>
                                    @Html.Partial("_EventData", prefixDay)
                                </td>
                            }
                        }

                        @foreach (var day in week.DaysInWeek)
                        {
                            <td class="currentMonthBackground">
                                @Html.Partial("_EventData", day)
                            </td>
                        }

                        @if (Model.SuffixDays.Any() && week.WeekNumber == Model.MonthData.NumberOfWeeks.Last())
                        {
                            foreach (var suffixDay in Model.SuffixDays)
                            {
                                <td>
                                    @Html.Partial("_EventData", suffixDay)
                                </td>
                            }
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="modalBodyContainer"></div>
</div>
```

mvc _eventdata.cshtml partial view:

```
@model Common.Calendar.DTODay

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-xs-1">
        @if (Model.IsCurrentDay)
        {

            <div class="circle">@Model.DayNumber</div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="@(Model.IsOtherMonth ? "otherMonthDay" : "currentMonthDay")">@Model.DayNumber</div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-1 mml5">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <span class="fa fa-plus" title="Toggle dropdown menu"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a onclick="addReminder('@Model.FullDate')"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> Reminder</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="addComment('@Model.FullDate')"><i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o fa-fw"></i> Note</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

@if (Model.ReminderCount > 0 || Model.NoteCount > 0 || Model.BirthdayCount > 0 || Model.Holiday != null)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @if (Model.NoteCount > 0)
            {
                <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs inline mobileReminder " onclick="displayNote('@Model.FullDate')">
                    <i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o fa-fw"></i><span class="eventSizeSmall">@Model.NoteCount</span>
                </a>
            }

            @if (Model.ReminderCount > 0)
            {
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs inline mobileReminder " onclick="displayReminder('@Model.FullDate')">
                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> <span class="eventSizeSmall">@Model.ReminderCount</span>
                </a>

            }

            @if (Model.BirthdayCount > 0)
            {
                <a class="btn btn-birthday btn-xs inline mobileReminder " onclick="displayBirthday('@Model.FullDate')">
                    <i class="fa fa-birthday-cake fa-fw"></i><span class="eventSizeSmall">@Model.BirthdayCount</span>
                </a>
            }

            @if (Model.Holiday != null)
                     {
                    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs mobileReminder" onclick="displayHoliday('@Model.FullDate')">
                        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn fa-fw"></i><span class="eventSizeSmall">1</span>
                    </a>
                }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved.  I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115052/bootstrap-how-to-set-up-fixed-width-for-td) SO question to answer it..

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Template:

```
<td style="width:14%">content</td>
```

Changed the width to 14px, then i removed bootstrap `btn`  border-width.

End results and happy camper:
[image]

And it also looks proper in mobile:
[image]