# Bootstrap table setting cell width problem

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, width, bootstrap-table

I have the following issue with my bootstrap table. I cannot set a custom width to cells at table head. Even if I do, it's not set. I searched and learned that bootstrap does prevent that by adding padding to cells. But it still didn't work when I added padding:0 to each cell at table head. Anyways let me show the code and screenshots

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-white">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="max-width: 1%;">#</th>
          <th style="max-width: 48.5%;">Component</th>
          <th style="max-width: 2.5%;">Unit Cost</th>
          <th style="max-width: 2.5%;">Qty</th>
          <th style="max-width: 2.5%;">Currency</th>
          <th style="max-width: 13%;">WBS</th>
          <th style="max-width: 14%;">Purchase Type</th>
          <th style="max-width: 10%;">Vendor</th>
          <th style="max-width: 2%;"></th>
          <th style="max-width: 2%;"></th>
          <th style="max-width: 2%;"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this as you can see the width is not applied

[image: It looks like this as you can see the width is not applied]

However it should look like this without scrollbar.

[image: However I want it to look at least like this. Without]

So my questions are

1. How can I apply fixed width to those cells?
2. How can I make the table look 100% visible without that scrollbar. Somehow squeezing it

Thanks, beforehand. If anything else needs to be shared let me know, please.

Comment: try using table layout fixed and widths rathewr than max widths

Comment: ^have you tried @Pete's suggestion? possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115052/bootstrap-how-to-set-up-fixed-width-for-td)

Comment: @Pete, didn't worked

Comment: @reiallenramos, those solutions didn't worked for me :/

Comment: you're on Bootstrap 4 correct? I'm trying something else...

Comment: did you add a width of 100% to the table too?

Comment: @reiallenramos, I'm so sorry, just realized that I tagged bootstrap 4, I use 3 in project

Comment: @Pete, still didn't work :/

Comment: oh okay if that's the case you can't use width percentages with bootstrap. as suggested in the answer I linked earlier, you should use classes `<td class="col-md-2">A</td>`

Comment: Then you need to create a [mcve] of the problem

Comment: @reiallenramos, should I use them in th or td?

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/reiallenramos/dr6c8f0s/5/ . Notice I removed `table-responsive`. Let me know if it works so I can post as answer.

Comment: @reiallenramos no, mate it doesn't work when there exists data which is too long. Field therefore the table expands and scrollbar shows up

Comment: updated with longer text: https://jsfiddle.net/reiallenramos/dr6c8f0s/9/ . Are you talking about the scrollbar on the page itself or in the table?

Comment: in my case that didn't work as well :/ but @cgdannie 's solution removed the scrollbar. Anyways, I'm gonna try something else. Thanks for the help, man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable padding for all cells, not only the ones in the header.

If you do not want, that bigger content increases the column width, you should hide the overflow.

```css
.table-responsive td,
.table-responsive th {
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you want to resize the table to always fit into the screen, you would need some JavaScript.

```js
(function() {
  const responsiveTable = document.querySelector('.responsive-table table');
  responsiveTable.style.transformOrigin = '0 0';


  function resizeTable() {
    responsiveTable.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
    const tableWidth = responsiveTable.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    const resizeFactor = document.body.offsetWidth / tableWidth;
    responsiveTable.style.transform = `scale(${resizeFactor})`;
  }
  resizeTable();

  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeTable);
})();
```

```css
.responsive-table table {
  background-color: red;
}

.responsive-table td,
.responsive-table th {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 1</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 2</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 3</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 4</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 5</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 6</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 7</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 8</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 9</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 10</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 11</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 12</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 13</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 14</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 15</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 16</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 17</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 18</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 19</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Column 20</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
        <td>Some Content</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can code :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
...
 </table>
</div>
```

and style

```
.table-responsive {
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: Tried it but it just hides the scrollbar and the rest becomes not visible

Comment: <table class="table"> To <table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">