# Align table head with table content on bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to know a way to align the table head with the table content

The actual result is the following:
[image: Actual result]

As you can see, those are not aligned.
I need columns to be aligned without having a fixed width.

Title column should take all the remaining width.

Here is my actual code:

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="d-flex">
                <th scope="col" class="col-auto"><i class="fas fa-folder fa-lg"></i></th>
                <th scope="col" class="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col" class="col-auto">Author</th>
                <th scope="col" class="col-auto">NB</th>
                <th scope="col" class="col-auto">Last activity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="d-flex">
                <td scope="row"><a href=""><i class="fas fa-folder fa-lg"></i></a></td>
                <td class="col"><a href="">flap flap flap</a></td>
                <td><a href="">Dushy</a></td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>03:20:32</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use `col-auto` class. Replace `col-auto` class with `col` class.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="d-flex">
                <th scope="col" class="col-auto"><i class="fas fa-folder fa-lg"></i></th>
                <th scope="col" class="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col" class="col">Author</th>
                <th scope="col" class="col">NB</th>
                <th scope="col" class="col">Last activity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="d-flex">
                <td scope="col" class="col-auto"><a href=""><i class="fas fa-folder fa-lg"></i></a></td>
                <td scope="col" class="col"><a href="">flap flap flap</a></td>
                <td scope="col" class="col"><a href="">Dushy</a></td>
                <td scope="col" class="col">14</td>
                <td scope="col" class="col">03:20:32</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not the output expected. Author, NB and Last activity must take the least space possible, while Title should take all the remaining space. Here all columns except the first one have equal width

Comment: You can use class `col-md-*` or manual style. Here is the reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115052/how-to-set-up-fixed-width-for-td/34987484#34987484

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to avoid fixed width, but I guess that's impossible.